# Restore relative positions of views

Tags: c#, layout, view, xamarin.android, rangeslider

**EDIT:** I forgot to describe my actual probem :D After orientation changes, portrait -> landscape or vice versa, the thumbs do not layout correctly. I want a thumb thats in the middle (width / 2) of the layout to remain at the middle of the layout after orientation change.

I'm trying to create a "range slider".
What I have is 2 simple views, that represent the two thumbs and a frame layout that represents the slider.

I'm laying out my two thumbs in the overridden OnLayout method, based on the width of the slider multiplied by the value of a thumb (between 0 and 1).

```
public class RangeSliderView : ViewGroup
{

public RangeSliderView(Context context) : base(context)
{
    var thumbL = new Thumb(context);
    var thumbR = new Thumb(context);
    AddView(thumbL);
    AddView(thumbR);
}

protected override void OnLayout(bool changed, int l, int t, int r, int b)
{
    if (changed)
    {
        //Get the width and height if not set yet
        if (ThumbLeft.MeasuredWidth == 0 || ThumbLeft.MeasuredHeight == 0)
            ThumbLeft.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified), MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost));

        if (ThumbRight.MeasuredWidth == 0 || ThumbRight.MeasuredHeight == 0)
            ThumbRight.Measure(MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpecMode.Unspecified), MeasureSpec.MakeMeasureSpec(b, MeasureSpecMode.AtMost));

        //calculate width and the relative position of the thumbs
        int width = r - l;
        int thumbLeftX = (int)(width * lastProgressLeft); //last progresses are a value between 0 and 1
        int thumbRightX = (int)(width * lastProgressRight);

        //position the thumbs
        ThumbLeft.Layout(l: l + thumbLeftX,
                         t: t,
                         r: l + thumbLeftX + ThumbLeft.MeasuredWidth,
                         b: ThumbLeft.MeasuredHeight);
        ThumbRight.Layout(l: l + thumbRightX - ThumbRight.MeasuredWidth,
                          t: t,
                          r: l + thumbRightX,
                          b: ThumbLeft.MeasuredHeight);
    }
}
}
```

The values really seem to be correct, in the landscape, the "r" value is bigger than in portrait. "l" is always 0 since the control is aligned to the left of my screen. The calculation seems correct, I tested moving one of the thumbs to the middle, so I can exactly see if thumbLeftX or thumbRightX are 50% of the width. It seemed correct.

I think the Layout(...) calls on the thumbs do not layout my thumbs reliably.
Is there a layout call that I'm missing? 
Do I need to call other methods to re-layout my thumbs correctly?

Initially, the lastProgressLeft is 0 and the lastProgressRight is 1 (meaning thumb left should be at the left end of the slider, the right thumb at the right end of the slider. This works great, also on orientation changes, it looks correct.

Comment: How can we answer this question if everything seem correct? Please point out what not correct is.

Comment: damn i actually forgot to make that clear, i now edited it. its about the sliders not being layouted correctly, even tho the math seems to be correct

Comment: My guess is your two thumbs didn't get correctly measured when orientation changed, could you please provide complete codes of your custom view?

Comment: Well they dont get remeasured on orientation change, since their height and width remain the same. Thats why I have these "ifs" at the beginning